# Radomize order of <li> elements but group them by classes

Tags: jquery, list, random

I'm looking for a way to randomize the order of a list of `<li>` with jQuery but keeping them grouped by their class. So if I have like 3 levels of `<li>` I want them to appear in random order inside my `<ul>` but also keep the `<li>` with the highest level (defined by its class) grouped together at the top, then having the second highest group also in random order next, etc.

I have managed to use a function to reorder the items randomly but am not capable to group them by level. My knowledge of jQuery is quite basic.

Sample code before randomized order

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #1</a></li>
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #2</a></li>
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #3</a></li>

    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #4</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #5</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #6</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #7</a></li>

    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #8</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #9</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #10</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #11</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #12</a></li>
</ul>
```

EDITED: This is the script I use to randomize the order

```
var items = $("#myList > li");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length -1) + 1;
    var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length -1) +1;
    items.eq(target).before(items.eq(target2));
}
```

and I'm looking to have something like this order randomly generated.

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #3</a></li>
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #1</a></li>
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #2</a></li>

    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #6</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #4</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #7</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #5</a></li>

    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #10</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #12</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #9</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #8</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #11</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add the code that does the randomization, and then we'll be able to advice how to improve it to do grouping

Comment: Added the script on OP

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much there. The only change you need now is to consider items level by level, instead of all together. You can do it by filtering them according to their class containing a certain digit. For example:

```
var items = $("#myList > li[class*=3]");
```

would only find items with class name that contains 3, in your example that would be all "level3" items. When you shuffle these, the rest stay intact.

So overall you need to iterate these levels, and shuffle each separately. Something like that:

```js
var levels = ['1', '2', '3']
levels.forEach(function(level) {
  var items = $("#myList > li[class*=" + level + "]");
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
      var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length -1) + 1;
      var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length -1) +1;
      items.eq(target).before(items.eq(target2));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
<ul id="myList">
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #1</a></li>
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #2</a></li>
    <li class="level3"><a href="">Link #3</a></li>

    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #4</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #5</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #6</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="">Link #7</a></li>

    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #8</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #9</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #10</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #11</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="">Link #12</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrei. It works as intended.
That's exactly the quick solution I was looking for. You really helped me get there much quicker than I would on my own. Thanks